# What is the use of contains and contained in sequelize Where clause?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
  $contains: [1, 2]      // @> [1, 2] (PG array contains operator)
  $contained: [1, 2]     // <@ [1, 2] (PG array contained by operator)
```

I want to know what is the actual use of both above opeartor

Comment: They relate to [tag:PostgreSQL] [operators for arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html). The difference is whether the argument is the array to search for or search in, with the column value used for the other. MySQL, to my knowledge, does not have equivalents.

Comment: Thanks but i want to design a query in which i passed an array in where condition and match all list with array elements. If all records contain or matched with elements then the result display. Please help me

Comment: `WHERE foo IN (1,2,3)`  ?  (This is like `OR`.)

Comment: Thanks @Rick but  i need like AND that match all list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE foo IN (11,22,33)
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;   -- that is, all 3 were found
```

(This assumes there is only one row for each item in the IN clause.)